# update csv when I run the code in R several times

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

It is possible to save a data table in csv and then when I run the code again the new values are added to the previous data table, for example:

```
row<-t(rnorm(6))
df<-as.data.frame(row)
```

the result is:

```
> df
          V1        V2         V3        V4        V5         V6
1 -0.1610984 0.6665826 -0.6963656 0.5849711 -0.663874 -0.2146757
```

And now I save the result as `csv`:

```
write.csv(df, "database.csv")
```

so if I run the code again I would like it to be added to the previous data table and not overwrite the results, but as you know if I run the code again my csv file is overwritten and saves the last result.

I would like to have the following result when I open my csv file.

```
          V1        V2         V3        V4        V5         V6
1 -0.1610984  0.6665826 -0.6963656 0.5849711 -0.663874 -0.2146757
2 -0.09906008 1.799482   0.2739241 0.4983932  0.9533234 0.9050962
```

I want to implement the above to create a database of predictions.
it's possible?

Comment: have a look at the `append` argument to `write.csv`, i.e. `write.csv(df, "database.csv", append = TRUE)`

Comment: thanks but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Simon almost got it. You need to add one more argument to prevent column names being added again and again. Try this:

```
write.table(df, file="database.csv", sep=",", append=TRUE, col.names=FALSE)
```

I'm not sure why `write.csv` doesn't work. I'm looking into it...

Comment: thanks!!! here the solution: `write.table(data_final, "prediccion.csv", sep = ",", col.names = !file.exists("prediccion.csv"), append = T, row.names = F)`